# How to preview pdf in Scaffold - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using the flutter pdf producer package and I'm trying to preview or display it in the scaffold but so far unable to do it

package link : https://pub.dev/packages/pdf

here is my code

```
class _PreviewInvoiceState extends State<PreviewInvoice> {

  // pdf producer
  void makePdf(){
    final document = pw.Document();
    document.addPage(
        pw.Page(
          pageFormat: PdfPageFormat.a4,
          build: (pw.Context context) {
            return pw.Center(child: pw.Text('hello world'));
          }
        )
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(); // trying to display it in the scaffold body property
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package is for creating pdf. To view it you have to save it to storage with

```
// On Flutter, use the [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) library:
//   final output = await getTemporaryDirectory();
//   final file = File("${output.path}/example.pdf");
final file = File("example.pdf");
await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save());
```

And to view you have to use package like [pdf_viewer_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_viewer_flutter).